# How to use the same Apollo cache between page transitions in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I have the following apolloClient.js file from NextJS official examples repo:

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client'
import { concatPagination } from '@apollo/client/utilities'
import merge from 'deepmerge'
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'
import { useMemo } from 'react'

export const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = '__APOLLO_STATE__'

let apolloClient

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: new HttpLink({
      uri: 'https://nextjs-graphql-with-prisma-simple.vercel.app/api', // Server URL (must be absolute)
      credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      typePolicies: {
        Query: {
          fields: {
            allPosts: concatPagination(),
          },
        },
      },
    }),
  })
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
  // gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
    const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract()

    // Merge the existing cache into data passed from getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
    const data = merge(initialState, existingCache, {
      // combine arrays using object equality (like in sets)
      arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
        ...sourceArray,
        ...destinationArray.filter((d) =>
          sourceArray.every((s) => !isEqual(d, s))
        ),
      ],
    })

    // Restore the cache with the merged data
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(data)
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

  return _apolloClient
}

export function addApolloState(client, pageProps) {
  if (pageProps?.props) {
    pageProps.props[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME] = client.cache.extract()
  }

  return pageProps
}

export function useApollo(pageProps) {
  const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME]
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(state), [state])
  return store
}
```

I have two pages: page1.js where I use an Apollo hook (useQuery()) and a second page, page2.js which do nothing, only returns null. The problem is if I inspect the Apollo Cache using the Chrome Extension the cached result from query on page1 is not present on page2.

How can I use only 1 global cache and prevent reinitialising the cache between page transitions ?

Answer (score 0):

this might might be because of the way you navigate between page , if you are using an anchor `<a>` tag, then that will reload the app on navigation. instead use the nextJS Link component. Here is a small example from the official documentation. you can find more informtion here:  [nextjs Link component](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link)

```
import Link from 'next/link'

function Home() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Home</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link href="/blog/hello-world">
          <a>Blog Post</a>
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}

export default Home
```